# Fisk distribution in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, numpy

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-logistic_distribution), the Fisk distribution has two parameters, scale $\alpha$, and shape $\beta$. However, [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisk.html) has only `c` as the shape parameter.

If I am given $\alpha$ and $\beta$, how do I use them in SciPy?

I want to create a Fisk variable and then sample with `fisk.rvs(size=n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The Fisk distribution implements location `loc` and scale `scale` parameters for each distribution. So the `scale` parameter is $\alpha$. This is explained in the documentation for [`rv_continuous`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous), of which the Fisk distribution is a subclass. There's also a usage note in the documentation:

> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale parameters. Specifically, `fisk.pdf(x, c, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to `fisk.pdf(y, c) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

The shape parameter `c` is $\beta$ in the Wikipedia expression.